# Cross table creation with subqueries

Tags: pivot, crosstab

I need to make a table that will show how many cars have been sold depending on the car state (used or new) as well as its damage situation (damaged or not). Keep in mind that each car can have many DamageID's and many cars can have the same DamageID (I just need to count the cars that have been damaged). I need to print a table that will show on the X axis the State (NEW and USED) and then on the Y axis I need the damage condition of the car (damaged or not regardless of the type of damage and number of DamageID per car). I tried using the pivot table technique but I couldn't figure it out. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
Select 
(select Count(CD.CarDamageID)
From CarDamage as CD
inner join Invoice as I on I.CarInventoryID = CD.CarInventoryID
) as Damage
,
(select Count(I.InvoiceID)
From Invoice I
inner join CarInventory CI on CI.CarInventoryID = I.CarInventoryID
Inner join CarState CS on CS.CarStateID = CI.CarStateID
Where CS.[State] ='New') as NEW
,
(select Count (I.InvoiceID)
From Invoice I
inner join CarInventory CI on CI.CarInventoryID = I.CarInventoryID
Inner join CarState CS on CS. CarStateID = CI.CarStateID
Where CS.[State]='Used') as USED
```

This is what I have for now.

Comment: Not a well "asked" question Emil. Read SO notes on how to ask questions. This is a dense block of text! Any specific SQL product being used?

Answer (score 0):

For most SQL products you can use a normal 'group by' from a common table expression (CTE). e.g.

```
with damagecounts as (
  select
    cs.state as carstate
    ,i.carinventoryid
    ,cd.cardamageid
    ,case when cs.state = 'New' then 1 end as newdamage
    ,case when cs.state = 'Used' then 1 end as useddamage
  from cardamage as cd
  inner join invoice as i on i.carinventoryid = cd.carinventoryid
  inner join carinventory as ci on ci.carinventoryid = i.carinventoryid
  inner join carstate as cs on cs.carstateid = ci.carstateid
  where cs.state in ('New', 'Used')
)
select
  carstate
  ,carinventoryid
  ,count(newdamage) as newdamage
  ,count(useddamage) as useddamage
from damagecounts
group by carstate, carinventoryid
order by carstate, carinventoryid
```

With Postgres etc, you get filters that make it simpler

```
select
  cs.state as carstate
  ,i.carinventoryid
  ,count(cd.cardamageid) filter (where cs.state = 'New') as newdamage
  ,count(cd.cardamageid) filter (where cs.state = 'Used') as useddamage
from cardamage as cd
inner join invoice as i on i.carinventoryid = cd.carinventoryid
inner join carinventory as ci on ci.carinventoryid = i.carinventoryid
inner join carstate as cs on cs.carstateid = ci.carstateid
where cs.state in ('New', 'Used')
group by carstate, carinventoryid
order by carstate, carinventoryid
```

With Microsoft SQL Server you have the PIVOT statement, but this is getting far away from basic standard SQL